# Combining Multiple Paths / Parts in Adobe Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have created a design in Illustrator and am having difficulty combining the shapes/paths.

The goal is to make this:

[image: Interlocking Circles]

...which I have essentially made, but the pieces won't connect properly. When I use the pathfinder, it doesn't follow the contour and connects points that cut through the image like this:

[image]

Here's the AI file:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1rsfxcqknv50oy/Interlocking-Circles-Illustration-1.ai?dl=0

Any tips/help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/92254/63979

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make a **Blend** using two circles > Specified Steps = 4
- Make a **Blend** using two horizontal paths > Specified Steps = 6
- Select both blends and go to the **Menu Object** > **Blend** > **Expand**
- Select both blends and go to the **Menu Object** > **Ungroup**
- Select all and use the **Shape Builder Tool** holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to drag over the surplus segments and delete them

[image: BLENDS]

- Select the main paths, change the colors and delete the rest

[image: END]

Comment: OMG, this is amazing! My approach was totally wrong and this method makes it so simple! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Use the *Shape Builder Tool* instead (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>)

Select all the areas you want to connect, and then using the tool **Click + Drag** on the areas to connect.